# How to hide model properties in specific operations?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I got some issue with Swashbuckle.
We have a model *Student* like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public StudentStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in PUT operation, everthings is working fine, but in POST I want to delete the Id and status parameter from the body we have to send to the API.

Any idea on how to do this?

Many thanks to the one who'll solve this issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a separate model class that exactly represents what a client is allowed to send for each of the two operations. So in this case two separate classes, called something like StudentPostModel and StudentPutModel and including the desired fields in each one.

As well as making things confusing in Swagger, you also leave yourself open to over-posting attacks if you try to re-use the same model in different contexts like you're outlining.

Comment: Oh, OK. I get it. Unfortunately, my boss wants to use the same model everywhere. That's why we're stuck now. Thanks for the help though.